# bash: variable defining environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In Bash, this work:

```
FOO=foo BAR=bar a_command
```

But how to make it works?

```
ENV="FOO=foo BAR=bar"
$ENV a_command
```

I got:

```
FOO=foo: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
  sh -c "$ENV a_command"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [`env`](http://man.cx/env) command is for

```
env $ENV a_command
```

Note that the behaviour you see is [documented in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) -- the shell looks for variable assignments *before* expanding variables.